# How do I get all the unique values from a dataframe attached to the column/s they belong to?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I work for a mental health organization and I'm trying to pull unique session data from our database. The problem is as follows. Sometimes when new information is added like, for example, an additional signature, there's an entirely new line of duplicate information added with the same information except for that one new value. I need all unique information tied to a session (session_id). This is what it would look like as an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'session_id': [1, 1, 2, 3],
                     'signature': ['Bob', 'John', 'Bob', 'Bob'],
                     'patient_id': [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234],
                     'patient_name': ['Frank', 'Frank', 'Frank', 'Frank']})
df (example created for Jupyter Notebook)
```

This is what I want to create for every session:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'session_id': [1],
                       'signature': ['Bob'],
                       'signature_2':  ['John'],
                       'patient_id': [1234],
                       'patient_name': ['Frank']})
final_df
```

I want this output regardless of where the new unique value is. So if there was an additional patient involved in the session, a new column called patient_name_2 would be generated for the new dataframe. Any help would be much appreciated.

Alternatively, if this could be done from the DataBase level with some form of GROUP BY in MS SQL, let me know.

Comment: Are your assumptions here that the patient_id always is unique, session_id should always keep the lowest id and patient name is always the same?

Comment: Yep, the patient ID will always be tied to the patient name so if there was an additional patient involved then the ID would change as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with it afterwards, but one quick option that gives you something relatively easy to continue working with afterwards is a `.groupby` and `.agg`:

```
In [89]: df.groupby('session_id').agg(set)
Out[89]:
              signature patient_id patient_name
session_id
1           {John, Bob}     {1234}      {Frank}
2                 {Bob}     {1234}      {Frank}
3                 {Bob}     {1234}      {Frank}
```

You could also just iterate through the grouped dataframe instead of using `.agg` if you really want to create separate frames for each `session_id`.

Comment: Thanks, That works on the example dataset but not on my real one. I'm getting a InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. Not sure why. Going to look into it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on your final_df.
The solution joins all signatures to a list.

If you wanted to make a unique signature into unique columns, there will be a problem.

Example: Different patients have different numbers of unique signatures.
This would cause your dataframe to have many NaN values because of inconsistent columns length.

```
df_new = df.groupby(by=["patient_id", "patient_name"], as_index=False).agg({"signature":"unique", "session_id": "min"})
```